# Lambda and method reference in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, composition

In Compose, there is a moment when a lambda or a reference to a method is passed as a parameter and a recomposition occurs, then Compose regards this as another object

Explain how he defines it, preferably how it is compiled

In one of the articles it was mentioned `since Compose 1.4 stopped working due to the use of comparison by reference instead of the custom equals generated by Kotlin.` But I don't understand what it means